# Serialization of ManyToMany Field with a through model and having a self relationship

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model with a manytomanyfield having self relationship and through model. i want to have a serializer that gives the field of the through model. But can't find any luck.

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     relations = CarRelationSerializer(source='carrelation_set', many=True, read_only=True, allow_null=True)


    class Meta:
      model = Car
      fields = ("id", "color", "relations")

class CarRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
     model = CarRelation
     fields = "__all__"
```

The models for these are:

```
class Car(models.Model):
   color = model.CharField()
   relations = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="CarRelation")

class CarRelation(models.Model):
    source = model.CharField()
    target = model.CharField()
```

But in serialized data, i am not getting the source and target. Any help how to serialize this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the point of `CarRelation`. If taking into account only `Car`, you can serialize it as follows:

```py
class SimpleCarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = Car
      fields = ("id", "color")


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    relations = SimpleCarSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
      model = Car
      fields = ("id", "color", "relations")
```

Here we need another simple car serializer in order to not infinitely loop the relationships. Each car will show only the related cards.